# changing from 32bit to 64bit .NET MVC dev.. Changing individual project properties to x64 causes error?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Just converted my .NET 4.7 MVC5 app to 64bit. Interestingly if I tried to change all the projects to 64bit, by right clicking each and going into each project's properties, I get a "badimage" error with one of them. However if I left them at "any CPU" and then changed the Solution Configuration Manager and changed the Platform to x64, this worked. This last change seemed to propagate to all projects in the Configuration Manager view, including the project that was giving me problems.

When I re-inspect under project / properties / Build , the platform target is set at "Any CPU".

Any enlightenment on this greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Web projects should always use Any CPU, and then when deployed to IIS, choose the bitness from application pool advanced settings.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am deploying to Azure App Services via "publish". So are you saying that as long as I set the App Service to 64bit, then AnyCPU will pick this up and run as 64bit.?

Comment: I asume the exception you got is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2 It contaisn two possible sources of error and how to solve them too. It is not uncommon for parts of the Compilation and execution process (like JiT, ILDasm.exe) to work differently based on the target platform.

Comment: Thanks. At the moment I am specifying 64bit via the solution config manager, but unsure whether this is correct or whether I should leave it at "anyCPU" and setup Azure app Service to 64bit and then just publish.